# While developing the chrome extension,while clicking the popup.html file the web page shows "page not found."

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop the chrome extension but and as soon as I pass the data to popup.html it shows page not found error.

below is the code of popup.js page:-

```
             // When the popup HTML has loaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(evt) {

    // Get the event page
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(eventPage) {
        // Call the getPageInfo function in the event page, passing in 
        // our onPageDetailsReceived function as the callback. This injects 
        // content.js into the current tab's HTML
        eventPage.getPageDetails(onPageDetailsReceived);
    });
     }); 

      function onPageDetailsReceived(pageDetails)  { 


        document.getElementById('title').value = 'abcd';
        document.getElementById('location').value = 'abcd'; 
       document.getElementById('email').value = 'abcd';     
        document.getElementById('skill').value =  'abcd';

        document.getElementById('contact').value = 'abcd'; 

         }
```

below is the code of popup.html page in which I have added the form where the details is to be passed
:-

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body { 
                min-width: 420px; 
                overflow-x: hidden; 
                font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
                font-size: 12px; 
            }
            input, textarea { 
                width: 420px; 
            }
            input#save { 
                font-weight: bold; width: auto; 
            }
        </style>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="addbookmark">
            <p><label for="title">Title</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="title" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="location">Location</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="location" name="location" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p><label for="email">Email</label><br />
            <input type="email" id="email" name="title" size="50" value="" /></p>


            <p><label for="contact">Contact</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p>
             <p><label for="skill">Skills</label><br />
            <input type="skill" id="skill" name="skill" size="50" value="" /></p>
            <p>
                <input id="refer" type="submit" value="Refer Your Friend" />
                <span id="status-display"></span>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

manifest.json :-

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Chrome Extension",
    "description": "Chrome Extension",
    "version": "0.2",
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["event.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs", 
       "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Does your popup.html contain only javacript code??

Comment: NO the popup.html is having html code for a form which is actully calling the popup.js file written above.

Comment: Then share full code

Comment: Edited the desired code

Comment: Add the contents of `manifest.json`, I'm suspecting a typo.

Comment: Can you also share the file/folder structure of your extension?

Comment: yes, sure. my folder contain following files:-
manifest.json
popup.html
event.js